# HTML select box and selective redirection

Tags: html

How can I allow only one option value to redirect, but the others are just choices.
In other words, users can select any option they like, but if they chose one particular option say option4, they will be redirected to another page.

Something like:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Text1">Title 1</option>
<option value="Text2">title2</option>
<option value="Text3">Title 3</option>
<option value="some page URL">Title 4</option>
```

I want only last option to be redirected.
All the other options are posted as variables.

I tried to use the onchange code from within the option 4 value but that does not work.

Can anyone help please

This is working perfectly, but I want

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping the value of each option as a typical value, and storing the URL in a unique attribute on each option. Your onchange logic could check whether the unique attribute is empty, and redirect if it isn't (in case you later want to add more redirect options).

For example:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-url'] && (window.location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-url'].value);">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Title 1</option>
<option value="2">title2</option>
<option value="3">Title 3</option>
<option value="4" data-url>Title 4</option>
```

I would also recommend moving your onchange script into a `<script>` tag or javascript file.